# how to set the position of a div to be relative to another one

Tags: html, css, forms

i have a PHP and HTML code that use Google map and i have a form that includes some fields where it gets  the user input and return the result connected to the databases.

the problem is that i want to set the position of the form beside the Google map.

i do not know how to do it using CSS.

here how it looks :

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#form {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  margin: auto;
  width: 550px;
  height: 450px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #09C;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: inset 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
[![enter image description here][1]][1] code: =====
<html>

<head>
  <title>Custom Markers</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>

  < /head>

    <body>
      <div id="map">
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `float: left;` on your `#map` or use `display: inline-block;`

Maybe you should take a look at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) to get the basics of css.

And how you said in the title of the question:
How to set position relative...

Use `position: relative;`

Comment: I'd advise against using floats when flexbox could be used for this very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use responsive frameworks such as bootstrap. however here's simple css solution.

```
.wrapper {
clear: both;https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le3k5.png
display: block;
content: "";
width: 100%;
}
#map {
float: left;
height: 400px;
width:800px;
}
#form {
float: left;
width: calc(100%-800px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both elements in a container and define there width so that they fit both next to each other.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="form"></div>
</div>
```

In the css you then go something like this:

```
#container {
 display: flex
}

#map { 
width: 60%;
}

#form {
width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use flexbox to align two boxes in the same container. Adapt to your needs.

**Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/L15Lr2a4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  Left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  Right
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container div {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background-color: orange;
}

.right {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```